# c# WinForms UserControl утечка памяти

Tags: c#, winforms, usercontrol

друзья. Разрабатываю масштабный проект на c# WinForms, столкнулся с проблемой утечки памяти. Проект имеет немалое количество UserControl, заметил при добавлении на форму данных контролов нагружается память, а вот после очистки базовой формы, память не очищается.

Примеры:

Один из модулей "Расписание", загружает необходимые UserControl'ы на экран.
Память поднимается под 290к

[image]
После удаление данного модуля с экрана, память не меняется.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал удалять основной контрол с помощью:

```
this.RemoveAt()
this.Cntrols.Clear()
control.Dispose()
```

Не помогает и принудительная очистка:

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Также, почитав о данной проблеме, говорят, что необходимо сбрасывать ссылки на события. Каждый UserControl имеет небольшое количество событий, пример:

```
 public event EventHandler entryClick = null;
        public event EventHandler entryMouseEnter = null;
        public event EventHandler entryMouseLeave = null;
        private DataEntry entryData = null;

        public AtlantControlEntry()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Click += items_Click;
            this.MouseEnter += items_mouseEnter;
            this.MouseLeave += items_mouseLeave;

            for (int i = 0; i < this.Controls.Count; i++)
            {
                this.Controls[i].Click += items_Click;
                this.Controls[i].MouseEnter += items_mouseEnter;
                this.Controls[i].MouseLeave += items_mouseLeave;
            }
        }

        // Working with the form-action // ->

        public void items_Click(object s, EventArgs e)
        {
            entryClick(s, e);
        }

        public void items_mouseEnter(object s, EventArgs e)
        {
            entryMouseEnter(s, e);
        }

        public void items_mouseLeave(object s, EventArgs e)
        {
            entryMouseLeave(s, e);
        }

        // Working with the form-action // <-

        ...
```

Но как их сбрасывать не имею понятия.
Буду благодарен любой помощи, заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вы гаданием занимаетесь. Берите профайлер памяти и смотрите где конкретно утечка.

Comment: Утечка памяти - это ситуация, когда потребление памати приложением постоянно растет. Если при каждом открытии формы память выедается все больше и больше, пока приложение не начинает падать с исключением OOM - тогда да, это утечка. А в вашем случае - может быть память ушла на подгрузку / нативную компиляцию контролов, которые до этого в приложении не использовались. Или на что-то еще - единственный способ узнать, на что именно - использовать профайлер.

Comment: У вас события контрола делегируются на методы в этом же контроле. В таком случае отписываться от события не нужно, так как наружу ссылки не торчат. И не факт, что у вас утечка. Сборщик не постоянно уничтожает объекты и даже более того, если памяти много, то он оставляет область под кучу зарезервированной или типа того. Попробуйте несколько раз пересоздать эти контроля в главном окне и увидите, есть у вас утечка или нет.

Comment: @John, пробую открыть данный модуль несколько раз: память 300к, 600к, 900к - это нормально?

Comment: @Никита это наверное, всё же мегабайты, а не килобайты? Вы открываете через интерфейс или программно подряд? Просто сборщик, тоже не мгновенно начинает очищать. Но вообще такое потребление не нормально. Нужно и правда профилировать. А вообще это x64 приложение и сколько озу на устройстве?

Comment: @John, открываю через интерфейс, могу с вами связаться в более удобном месте, буду очень благодарен помощи, покажу детально эту часть.

Comment: @Никита ну тут я вряд-ли смогу как-то помочь, я вообще в WinForm не очень, поэтому просто особенности могу не знать.

Comment: @John, понятно, спасибо и за это.